# tcolorbox theorems without numbering

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox

I'm getting used to the great package `tcolorbox`. Makes documents much more fun to read for students.

One thing I'd like to do : while numbering theorems is fine, I'd like my definitions, remarks and so on to be unnumbered. And I would like it to be done without having to type `\begin{definition*}` each time.

I browsed the documentation, and several posts on this site, but couldn't find any easy way. The only thing I found is this trick :

```
\newtcbtheorem{defin}{Définition}{breakable,enhanced,colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{defin}
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{defin*}}{\end{defin*}}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `\begin{definition}...\end{definition}` simpler than `\begin{defin*}...\end{defin*}`??? Also, your wrapping of the `defin*` environment will probably gobble the text content of the environment,unless you provide the 2 mandatory arguments of `defin`

Comment: Addition: Or the one mandatory argument of  `defin*` ....

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it in a macro, called, say, `\mynicetheoremwrapperforlaziness`, this way you get rid of the `\begin{...}...\end{...}`.

Is that quicker than `\begin{defin*}...\end{defin*}`? Not really...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcbtheorem{defin}{Définition}{breakable,enhanced,colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{defin}
\newenvironment{definition}{%
  \begin{defin*}
  }{%
  \end{defin*}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mynicetheoremwrapperforlaziness}{+o+m}{%
  \begin{defin*}{\IfValueT{#1}{#1}}
    #2%
  \end{defin*}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{Mon dieu}
Stuff
\end{definition}

\mynicetheoremwrapperforlaziness{%

\blindtext

}

\mynicetheoremwrapperforlaziness[Foo Title]{%

\blindtext

}


\end{document}
```